# How can I create a Form Definition using REST API in Orbeon?

Tags: orbeon

I could [update and publish existing form definitions in Orbeon](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/api/persistence/crud.html):

> When you create, edit, or read form definition with Form Builder, form definitions are stored as Form Builder data. That is, they are stored under: `/crud/orbeon/builder/data/[FORM_DATA_ID]`. On the other hand, when Form Builder publishes a form definition, it stores it where Form Runner will find it, that is under: `/crud/[APPLICATION_NAME]/[FORM_NAME]/form`. For example, this is what happens when saving and publishing a form definition `acme/demo` with a single attachment.

However, I don't know how to create a new Form Definition using REST API. Can someone please provide me an example of the REST call for creating a new form definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, the easiest way is to create an empty form in Form Builder, save it, and then retrieve the XML stored in the `orbeon_form_data` table in the newly added row, in the `xml` column (assuming you're using a relational database). Then, with that XML in hand, you can write your own code that creates a new row through the [CRUD API](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/api/persistence/crud.html).

Also, [RFE 3080](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/3080) covers an enhancement that might make this easier for you. It was written with creating new instances of forms you created in Form Builder mind, not new instances of a form definition, but in essence the idea is the same.

Comment: thanks, I could create a Form Definition though the CRUD API. I just had to add the Orbeon-Form-Definition-Version header in PUT request and it worked.

Comment: Excellent; I'm glad it worked, and thank you for the update.